# Determining active and passive roles between objects, during early design stage

Tags: object, oop, design-patterns

When modeling the interaction between two objects, I sometimes find myself considering which object should be active in the interaction and which should be passive, or whether the interaction should be managed by a third-party controller.

As an example let's assume we have an **Item** and a **Container**.

Three possible ways to handle the interaction between them could be.

1. item.Drop(container)
2. container.Store(item)
3. StorageController.Store(item, container)

Assuming all 3 approaches (and several others) can be correct in a given situation, what kind of considerations do you make to reach the most sustainable design choice?

The question is intentionally generic as I'm interested in the general principles people apply when assigning roles to objects, particularly if the overall architecture is at its early stages and it's yet not clear the level of responsibility that each object will take over time.

Comment: Model the domain. Give the software objects the same roles as the real-world objects they represent.

Comment: There's a heuristic called Do It Myself documented by Peter Coad that favors option 2, even if an object can't do the action in the real world. A good example is rolling a die, which results in Die.roll(). I don't think there's a general rule.